# Location of template rendering in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Where in Symfony2 is template rendering launched?

I am asking for the most general class/method handling the template logic, I guess by launching the configured template engine, like Twig for example.

Or to put the question even more concretely ... a controller delegates the layout to a specific template, like example.html.twig ... where is this filename used and passed for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most general case, assuming you're using the FrameworkBundle (if you're using Standard Edition, you are), the `render` function just calls `$this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse`, just passing along the parameters.

Engines (like the twig engine) implement `Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface`.

You can check out `vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php` (and the other relevant files, like the ones in the TwigBundle), if you'd like to take a close look at how it works.